# When will predispatch event be called?

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, quote, wishlist, quoteitem

I want to know, if

```
 controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add
```

will only be called, when a product is added to cart from product page, or if this event will also be called, when I add a product, which is on the wishlist of the customer to the shopping cart.

I have to deal with inconsistencies regarding my shopping cart, since I want to remove other products with certain attributes, which shouldn't be able to buy them together.

On my platform, every product which can be sold is UNIQUE and they all have a quantity of one. But sometimes it happens, that the computation of the price will take a product twice into account of the calculation.

Do you have any ideas or experience with altering the quote of the current shopping cart and even with old quotes that might be loaded, when a current quote is not used anymore?

I can provide code examples, if you think, that they might help you to better understand my problem.

---

It may work, if I change this code

```
        <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
            <observers>
                <customoptions>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Namespace_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>checkoutCartProductAddBefore</method>
                </customoptions>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
```

to

```
        <sales_quote_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <customoptions>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Namespace_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>checkoutCartProductAddBefore</method>
                </customoptions>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_product_add_after>
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

`controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add` is dispatched everytime you call the url `checkout/cart/add`.

When you add something to the cart from the wishlist you won't call the url mentioned above. Instead `wishlist/index/cart` action will be called.

If you want a single event that is dispatched every time you add something to the cart you can use `sales_quote_product_add_after`. but this one is dispatched immediately after a product is added to the cart.

Comment: what do you think about my answer above?

i cannot well-format a comment for code.. therefore I used the answer function

Comment: It should work. I think